# Reordering Nested List Entries in Python

Tags: python, list

is there any shortcut to regroup a nested list like

```
[[a0,b0,c0],[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,b2]]
```

to give something like this

```
 [[a0,a1,a2],[b0,b1,b2],[c0,c1,c2]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
transposed = zip(*matrix)
```

`*matrix` applies all nested lists in `matrix` as separate arguments to the `zip()` function, as if you typed `zip(matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2])`; `zip()` takes input sequences and outputs new sequences *per column*.

Demo:

```
>>> matrix = [['a0', 'b0', 'c0'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'b2']]
>>> zip(*matrix)
[('a0', 'a1', 'a2'), ('b0', 'b1', 'b2'), ('c0', 'c1', 'b2')]
```

The output uses nested tuples; if you *require* nested lists, transform them after the fact with:

```
map(list, zip(*matrix))
```

or

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*matrix)]
```